# Nesting STL Container in itself N times

Tags: c++, templates, stl

Is there a way to nest a STL container in itself as a template argument in a repeating manner n times?

Example:

```
template<int Nesting>
struct Nester{
 vector<...> my_vec;
};

int main(){

Nester<3> nester;
//typeof(nester.my_vec) -> vector<vector<vector<int>>>


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like

```
template<unsigned Nesting>
struct Nester
{
    using vec_type = std::vector<typename Nester<Nesting - 1>::vec_type>;
    vec_type my_vec;
};

template<> struct Nester<1u>
{
    using vec_type = std::vector<int>;
    vec_type my_vec;
};

template<> struct Nester<0u>   
{
    // do nothing
};
```

This builds up a `Nester<Nesting>::vec_type` using recursion, such that `Nester<1u>::vec_type` is `std::vector<int>`, `Nester<2u>::vec_type` is `std::vector<std::vector<int> >` ....  until it defines `Nester<Nesting>::vec_type`.

Then `Nester<n>::my_vec` is of type `Nester<n>::vec_type` for `n` between `1` and `Nesting`.

The specialisation `Nesting<0u>` is there, since (without that specialisation) constructing a `Nesting<0u>` will give very deep recursion (and, depending on compiler implementation, result in either a diagnosable error or a crashing compiler).

I've used an `unsigned` type as the template parameter, since having a negative `Nesting` doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<int N>
struct Nester {
 typedef std::vector<typename Nester<N - 1>::type> type;
 type my_vec;
};

template<>
struct Nester<0> {
 typedef int type;
};

int main() {
 Nester<0> n0;
 Nester<1> n1;
 Nester<2> n2;
 Nester<3> n3;
 std::cout << typeid(n1.my_vec).name() << std::endl;
 std::cout << typeid(n2.my_vec).name() << std::endl;
 std::cout << typeid(n3.my_vec).name() << std::endl;
 n3.my_vec = 1; // just for test:
 // error: no known conversion from 'int' to 'const std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int, ...>>>
}
```